# How to find the 2nd highest value in a row with Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a row of the database like this:

```
1|abc|10|30|12
```

The biggest value is 30 and the second highest is 12. How can I get the second value for each row in my table?

Comment: try `unpivot` and `row_number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work with any number of columns, just make sure you add them to the concatenated list where labelled `merge_col` in my query below:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, second_highest
  from (select x.*,
               regexp_substr(merge_col, '[^|]+', 1, levels.column_value) as second_highest,
               row_number() over(partition by x.col1 order by to_number(regexp_substr(merge_col, '[^|]+', 1, levels.column_value)) desc) as rn
          from (select t.*, col3 || '|' || col4 || '|' || col5 as merge_col
                  from tbl t) x,
               table(cast(multiset
                          (select level
                             from dual
                           connect by level <=
                                      length(regexp_replace(merge_col,
                                                            '[^|]+')) + 1) as
                          sys.OdciNumberList)) levels)
 where rn = 2
```

**Fiddle test:**  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b446f/2/0

In other words, for additional columns, change:

```
col3 || '|' || col4 || '|' || col5 as merge_col
```

to:

```
col3 || '|' || col4 || '|' || col5 || '|' || col6 .........  as merge_col
```

with however many columns there are in place of the `......`

Comment: I got the impression that the user was looking for second greatest numerical value. I could be wrong; not much in the way of sample data.

Comment: That's what this does. As you can see, it returns 12 (the 2nd highest numerical value). It assumes the key column is his first column in the sample data. If it's some other column he can change the `partition by` or remove it altogether if he wants it done on a row by row basis. Logically it's not really any different from what you posted (unpivoting a concatenated list of values and then using an analytic function to rank, afterward selecting rank number 2).

Comment: But where are you converting to number? Is that `CAST(... AS sys.OdciNumberList)`?

Comment: You're right I forgot to convert back to number, as is it could have come up with the wrong rank (ex. 12 being higher than 110). Just added to_number to the order by.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve that. try this one for instance:

```
SELECT MAX('column_name') FROM 'table_name'
WHERE 'column_name' NOT IN (SELECT MAX('column_name') FROM 'table_name' )
```

You basically exclude the highest number from your query and then you select the highest out of the rest .

Comment: In this query you only find in one column and I want to find the second value in all the row.

Comment: You can expand it to add your other columns as well. that was just an example, you didn't post your table

Comment: Well, my table is about 50 columns. How can expand it to add other columns?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are all different:

```
select t.*,
       (case when col1 <> greatest(col1, col2, col3) and
                  col1 <> least(col1, col2, col3)
             then col1
             when col2 <> greatest(col1, col2, col3) and
                  col2 <> least(col1, col2, col3)
             then col2
             else col3
        end) as secondgreatest
from table t;
```

Comment: This question is about three columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you can concatenate all the columns as a comma-delimited list, then you can do the following (assuming you're looking for the second highest *numerical* value):

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT keycolumn1, keycolumn2, col1 || ',' || col2 || ',' || ... || ',' || colx AS other_columns
      FROM mytable
), d2 AS (
    SELECT keycolumn1, keycolumn2, LEVEL AS pos
         , TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(other_columns, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS cvalue
      FROM d1
   CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(other_columns, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
       AND PRIOR keycolumn1 = keycolumn1
       AND PRIOR keycolumn2 = keycolumn2
       AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT keycolumn1, keycolumn2, pos, cvalue FROM (
    SELECT keycolumn1, keycolumn2, pos, cvalue
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY keycolumn1, keycolumn2 ORDER BY cvalue DESC ) AS rn
      FROM d2
) WHERE rn = 2;
```

The above will return the second-highest value for a given set of "key" column values along with the position of the column in which that value is found. I use concatenation and `CONNECT BY` to unpivot the table.